# How get ip with DNS and LWIP?

Tags: c, tcp, dns, stm32, lwip

I am using STM32F407 and lwip with uC-OS and I want to take ip from dns. I try to call this function.

```
ip_addr_t TargetIp;
dns_gethostbyname("www.google.com", &TargetIp, NULL, NULL);
```

But, this function return -5 (ERR_INPROGRESS). In addition if I write "192.168.10.15" instead of "www.google.com" there was no problem.  How can I take ip with DNS or another method.

Comment: From the documentation for that function: "ERR_INPROGRESS enqueue a request to be sent to the DNS server for resolution if no errors are present." Just from the name of the "error", it's clear that this means that the request is in progress.

Comment: Thank you for the information that give you. I understood what I should do. But I didn't understand how can I do. I can not send a request any DNS server. Should I write a callback function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved! I fixed function call of dns_gethostbyname

```
dns_gethostbyname("www.google.com", &TargetIp, dnsFound, NULL);
```

and I wrote a callback function which name is dnsFound like this.

```
void dnsFound(const char *name, ip_addr_t *ipaddr, void *arg) 
{       
    dns_gethostbyname("www.google.com", &TargetIp, dnsFound, NULL);
}
```